# cannot call static method from MainViewController from CDVPlugin class objective c and phonegap

Tags: objective-c, cordova, xcode4.6

I need to call static method from MainViewController **to add Progress Bar**, this progress bar show downloading progress from connection object in CDVPlugin class.

I make static method in MainViewController like:

```
+ (void)CommonMethod
{}
```

and defined it in MainViewController.h too like:

```
+ (void)CommonMethod;
```

I want to call it in class which is inherited from CDVPlugin, it's a bridge with javascript side.

I call it by two ways:
1-

```
MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mainView CommonMathod];
```

OR
2-

```
[MainViewController CommonMathod];
```

But, the two was result this warning which stop all of my app completely.

**instance method '-CommonMethod' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**

What can I do ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Are you sure, taht you need static method, may be simple function will work?

Comment: I need to call it from another class, another class inherited from CDVPlugin, so i couldn't to add progress bar from this class and i had to call method in main class to add this progress bar, IF their is ant solution to add this progress bar, i'll be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
[[MainViewController class] CommonMethod];
```

it is helpful

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :), If I can ask too, if this way is the best to add progress bar , by make MainViewController do that ?, now i see that progress bar should be static too.

Comment: I really can't answer that. I don't know what MainViewController is/suppose to do. Or what your progress bar should do.

Comment: The another class is responsible for downloading files from server, so it need to add progress bar to show this downloading progress, but it inherited from CDVPlugin (it's an interface with javascript side), and MainViewController is the main class of project and has its .xib file, so I though that the only solution is call MainViewController to add this progress bar on screen, IF you have any idea, i'll be very appreciated. And Thank you in all cases.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Phongap so i don't know exactly how it works. Usually a iOS app has many ViewControllers so the progress bar is usually added to the view controller that needs it. However if this solution only has one (MainViewController) you should probably add it to that. If you have a .xib just add your progress bar to that and connect it to your view controller and hide/show it when needed.

Comment: Thank you, i followed that and succeeded,

Answer (score 0):

Need

```
#improt "MainViewController.h"
```

And call with

```
[MainViewController CommonMathod];
```